# how to add multiple values to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Context:

I have the following code that i am trying to fix. This code filters the albums on my website (custom wordpress post type called "freealbums").

The code filters the freealbums by artists (custom post type called "artists") and the code works good, but I am trying to make a filter to allow people to sort the freealbums post type by:

```
artist, upcomingartist and producer
```

Instead of just the artist post type but I cant seem to add multiple post types to this code and make it work.

```
if(isset($_GET['a']) && intval($_GET['a']) != 0) {

  $atts = themex_get_query(themex_get_posts('freealbum',array('ID'),-1, array('artists','upcomingartist'=>$_GET['a'])), $limit, $paged); 

} else {

  $atts = array(
    'post_type'       =>'freealbum',
    'posts_per_page'  => $limit,
    'paged'           => $paged,
    'meta_key'        => '_thumbnail_id',
  ); 

} 

query_posts($atts);
```

Here is what i did to try and add another post type:

```
if(isset($_GET['a']) && intval($_GET['a']) !=0) {

  $atts=themex_get_query(themex_get_posts('freealbum',array('ID'),-1, array('artists','upcomingartist'=>$_GET['a'])), $limit, $paged); 

} else {
  $atts=array(
    'post_type'       =>'freealbum',
    'posts_per_page'  => $limit,
    'paged'           => $paged,
    'meta_key'        => '_thumbnail_id',
  ); 
} 

query_posts($atts);
```

As you can see all i changed was the following piece of code

```
array('artists'=>$_GET['a'])),
```

To This

```
array('artists','upcomingartist'=>$_GET['a'])),
```

I thought this would work but for some WEIRD reason the filter will now work with the `upcomingartist` post type but it stops working with the artist post type.

not sure what i am doing wrong.. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Can you show the contents of this function: `themex_get_posts()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put both filters (currently you are filtering by `upcomingartist` and passing weird `0 => 'artists'` as the second filter):

```
- array('artists','upcomingartist'=>$_GET['a'])),
+ array('artists'=>$_GET['a'],'upcomingartist'=>$_GET['u'])),
```

To filter on `upcomingartist` **only** use the following:

```
array('upcomingartist'=>$_GET['u'])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i tried what you suggested and the artist filter works however the upcoming artist one still doesnt seem to work

here is the full code i have for the query
`if(isset($_GET['a']) && intval($_GET['a'])!=0) {
 $atts=themex_get_query(themex_get_posts('freealbum',array('ID'),-1, array('artists'=>$_GET['a'],'upcomingartist'=>$_GET['u'])), $limit, $paged);
} else {
 $atts=array(
  'post_type' =>'freealbum',
  'posts_per_page' => $limit,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id',
 );
}
query_posts($atts);`

Comment: It’s evident that you should supply the `upcomingartist` as `u` in your `GET` request for this to work. There is no woodoo magick. If you want to retrieve the albums for upcomingartist **only**, the filter is to be: `array('upcomingartist'=>$_GET['u'])`.

Comment: i need it to filter by artist, upcoming artist OR producer... 
i have three html boxes in the sidebar.... one is full of artists name one with upcoming artists names and one with the producers names the artists link like this "http://www.bamofficial.com/free-downloads/?a=271" with the "?a=271" being the filter, the upcoming artists link like this "http://www.bamofficial.com/free-downloads/?u=271" with the "?u=271" being the filter, and the producers link like this "http://www.bamofficial.com/free-downloads/?p=271" with the "?p=271" being the filter. so it depends which name they select

Comment: would i need three separate filter codes to accomplish this?

Comment: “would i need three separate filter codes to accomplish this”—yes, you will. `_GET['p']` will retrieve the query param named `p` from the request address (e.g. `bamofficial.com/free-downloads/?p=271`.)

Comment: i figured it out... i need to use elseif like this 

`//query args
if(isset($_GET['a']) && intval($_GET['a'])!=0) {
 $atts=themex_get_query(themex_get_posts('freealbum',array('ID'),-1, array('artists'=>$_GET['a'])), $limit, $paged);
} 

elseif(isset($_GET['u']) && intval($_GET['u'])!=0) {
 $atts=themex_get_query(themex_get_posts('freealbum',array('ID'),-1, array('upcomingartists'=>$_GET['u'])), $limit, $paged);
}

else {
 $atts=array(
  'post_type' =>'freealbum',
  'posts_per_page' => $limit,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id',
 );
}

query_posts($atts);`

Comment: Probably yes. I don’t care the businesslogic inside, I just answered how you should rearrange a query to yield what you wanted.

Comment: on a side note [p] can't be used to filter as anylink with ?p=anynumber will try and redirect you to that post, so i had to try another letter and it worked

Answer (score 0):

array_push — Push one or more elements onto the end of array

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana");
array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");
print_r($stack);
```

**IN YOUR CODE :**

```
array_push($someArray['upcomingartist'], $_GET);
```

[## LINK](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)